# getting premature end of file error ie: could not able to load .config file

Tags: php, html, http, https

Using metadata compilation tool to compile xml file while loading xml file getting premature EOF error: [image: error screenshot]

`product.config` file contains

```
<product xmlns:xsi-"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="<URLpath for .xsd file>" name="<name> id="id">
    <description> hi this is sample discription
    </description>
</product>
```

HTTP Not working:

```
xmlns:xsi-"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

HTTPS fixes issue:

```
xmlns:xsi-"https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

What is the root cause of this issue?
Without modifying `product.config` from `http` to `https` how could I fix it?